# Can we load basic javascript function in a webview?

Tags: android-webview

I have implemented a function in webview. I put the javascript function in the html head then load it through web.loadUrl but the webview does not take the function into consideration. Is it possible to load it this way ? or am I on the wrong track ?

```
 "<td><a href='' onclick=\"displaying('image url')\" id=/image"+my_image[i] +"/"+"

 class='popup-open'><img 

src='"+my_image[i]+"'"+


                "width='80' height='65'></a></td></tr><tr>";

the hmtl content

   String webData = "<!DOCTYPE html>" +

                "<head> "+

                "<script>"+"function displaying(url)

{document.getElementById('image').innerHTML =\"<img src=\"url\" width=\"100\" height=\"105\">\";}"+"</script>"
                +
                " </head><body>"+ html_content +"</tr></table></body></html>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe is your JavaScript or some syntax shit. First of all, try to figure out what's the error message from WebKit engine.

To display webview's javascript messages, put onConsoleMessage in implementation.

```
   myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage cm) {
                Log.d(cm.message() + " -- From line "
                        + cm.lineNumber() + " of "
                        + cm.sourceId());
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Make sure you have following enabled

```
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: but is it possible to load javascripit inside webView ?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean? You have few options:

1. load javascript as a part of webpage (see jQuery.getScript method)
2. load script with html script tag

But if you want to expose your java android code to webview's html page, then you just need to create a java class with methods, make it available to webview's content

    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "SOME_NAME");

And then call it in your client side code

if (SOME_NAME) { SOME_NAME.METHOD1()  }